# An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

```
Window owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsActive);
if (owner == null)
    owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault();
```

On execution of last line,I am getting the error as:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll

This error is coming once I upgraded from VisualStudio 2012 to VisualStudio 2015.

What Configuration I have to do to resolve this error?

Comment: Can you give more information on how you are getting this error, like any specific code or while creating a project ? Please add detailed steps.

Comment: @RaviA. The code is:-                                                                                     Window owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsActive);
  if (owner == null)
        owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault();                                           on execution of last line i am getting that error.

Comment: Please add it to the question.Which line of the code you are getting this error ?

Comment: @RaviA.I have added the code in question.